# Difference between json and rss?

Tags: web-services

What is the difference between rss and json?

My knowledge is that these two are all data support(feed info)..

I want to know advantages and disadvantages of using these two and 
performance between these two? 
Which one is better for android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RSS (Rich Site Summary) and JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) are the
>   program-readable formats of data. Web publishers make these feeds so
>   their content will be easily accessible for re-use.
>
> The difference between RSS and JSON really lie in how they are parsed.
>   Although they are both strings (RSS is essentially just plain-text
>   XML),  JSON is far lighter-weight than RSS. Even though RSS is
>   plain-text, it will still have to be parsed/traversed in a
>   DOM/ElementTree similar to how one would read raw HTML data. As you
>   can imagine this can be a big pain. JSON is a string that can be
>   easily evaluated into a JavaScript object and traversed naively.
>
> Another big advantage to JSON over RSS is that you can read it
>   remotely using JSONP, whereas RSS blocks cross-domain requests. This
>   means that you would have to use a programming language which operates
>   on the server's side (e.g. PHP/Ruby/Python) in order to download that
>   page as a proxy and then parse it.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/z3jl5/eli5_the_difference_between_the_rss_and_json/c61bvi5/).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't read RSS feeds from remote sites, so you're limited to your own domain. JSON, however, works cross-domain. Its the biggest one.

Another is,

The difference between RSS and JSON really lie in how they are parsed. Although they are both strings (RSS is essentially just plain-text XML), JSON is far lighter-weight than RSS. Even though RSS is plain-text, it will still have to be parsed/traversed in a DOM/ElementTree similar to how one would read raw HTML data. As you can imagine this can be a big pain. JSON is a string that can be easily evaluated into a JavaScript object and traversed naively.